# Retrieving Multiple images using hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap

I would like to ask how do I retrieve images at the same time for example if I enter letters abc after clicking done a 3 images will apear corresponding to what I have inputted

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if I have understood well you want to show one image for each of the chars entered as input.

So you keep a hashmap, where the key is the character and the value is the image you want to show for that character. After you break down the input to separate characters, you find the separate images to be displayed using the `variable_name.get(Object key)` method, so in this case you will pass the separate chars as the parameter one after the other. After retrieving the images you display them.

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. can you try to go to this post please      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821057/getting-the-keyvalueimage-in-drawable-in-hashmap-using-loop-and-conditions because this is our code and maybe you can tell us what is wrong with our code because we have tried almost all possbile solutions but still no luck.